# Why after compressing ExtJS 4.2 app with Sencha Cmd do I get error, "c is undefined"?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I am making changes so we can use Sencha Cmd to minify our code.

But when I try to run the app, I'm getting an error: c is undefined

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Is it possible this might be due to YUI Compressor obfuscation?

If so, is it possible to not obfuscate, and just minify?

Are there strategies for dealing with obfuscation errors?

For troubleshooting purposes, can I obfuscate but not minify?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Two things it seems I need to do. When doing global search/replace to change class namespace paths, do not inadvertently add paths inside controller   views: []     configs.

Also, it seems if you have a store that loads its data later, you must have autoLoad: false, and possibly autoSync: false as well.